# Register r1 and r2 in boot process

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, boot-loader, device-tree

Please tell me about the register r1 and r2 that bootloader uses to pass the information to the kernel. What are they? where are they located? and some details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about the ARM Linux boot protocol, r1 and r2 are CPU registers. There are 16 general-purpose registers on 32-bit ARM processors, named r0-r15.

Comment: Thank you very much, now its more clear. maybe you could send a link for some basic info about that registers?

Comment: The registers are the central part of a register oriented processor, which most modern processors are. There are numerous web pages describing CPU architecture, for example: http://www.davespace.co.uk/arm/introduction-to-arm/registers.html

Comment: On ARM, the interface between the bootloader and the kernel is defined by these registers r1 & r2: r1 = machine type number discovered in (3) above, r2 = physical address of tagged list in system RAM, or physical address of device tree block (dtb) in system RAM.

Source: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/arm/Booting